# https before address shows only files in private_html folder on host

Tags: ssl, https, cloudflare

when i try my webpage address with https, page shows only files in the private_html folder not public_html.
but my website runs in the public_html. for example i use an index.html file (including forwarder script) and when you type https://alirezah.net it redirects to http://alirezah.net.
how can i fix it? I wanna use cloudflare ssl service but this happens.
I tried to edit htaccess but it doesn't help

Answer (score 7):

If your website is hosted on Directadmin, then follow these steps:

1. Log in to your DirectAdmin control panel
2. Click on Domain Setup
3. Click on the domain name you wish to change this for
4. Choose the `Use a symbolic link from private_html to public_html - allows for same data in http and https` checkbox.
5. Note the warning message - **anything in private_html will be removed**, so be sure you do not have content left here that you want to keep.
6. Accept the warning notice and your now pointing you are private_html directory to the public_html directory.

Comment: Thanks. it worked. is there any way to make website always run by https? for e.g. i like my website be redirected from http:// alirezah.net to https:// alirezah.net

Comment: @Steven http://stackoverflow.com/a/6847810/811922 may help. btw,please don't forget to accept the answer and vote up. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Saved what would be a potentially long time, contacting my host.

Answer (score 0):

If your [website](https://oglasevanjenaspletu.si) is installed in `private_html` it will be deleted using this function. If you want to keep your website installed in private html and also redirect http to https, then you need to create a `.htaccess` file in `public_html` with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule .* https://example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```